# Looking for a killer javascript/website monitoring/debug tool

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a good way of monitoring and logging full exchange between website and the internet.

I know that this can be done with firebug. The main problem I have with it is, that it cannot persist log data over reloads.

Also, if would be very cool to have an ability to log javascript activity and filter the log by the action I'd like to debug (e.g. setting a cookie, change of attribute etc)

Does anyone know something that fits at least some of those requirements, and on the rest performs at least as well as firebug does?

Comment: There is a "Persist" button in Firebug

Comment: ) oh... how could I miss it?? )) would you know how to log javascript activity with it as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out one of the many JavaScript logging utilities, like [log4js](http://log4js.berlios.de/).  You could use it and or something like [PantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/) to build automated testing / monitoring of your web applications.  The discussion around JavaScript logging on StackOverflow is pretty good too.  Check out these questions:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423267/are-there-any-logging-frameworks-for-javascript
2. [A JavaScript frontend logging system that logs to our backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033987/a-javascript-frontend-logging-system-that-logs-to-our-backend)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm mainly looking for something that would let me monitor JS activity without the JS having to log its own actions. Would you know of something like that?

Comment: @ArsenZahray When you say "JS Activity", do you mean in terms of the DOM or some other client action ?  Can you expand on the question ?

Comment: DOM, JS function calls, mostly dom though. Basically, I want to open it and see everything that the JS was doing on/with the page

Comment: Again, you might want to check out PhantomJS (it's a headless web browser, there are others): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814757/headless-internet-browser

Answer (score 3):

You could try fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: looks like a really amazing tool!